# NSurl connection delegates are not called

Tags: iphone

This is my code for getting image from url but the delegate methods are not getting invoked.why?

```
NSString *urlLink = [NSString stringWithString:appRecord.imageURLString];   
self.urlString=urlLink;
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlLink];
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
self.imageConnection=conn;
[conn release];
```

Comment: Have you add NSURLConnectionDelegate in Header file?

Comment: are you sure that connection is started? I mean did you check that conn != nil?

Comment: can you post how imageConnection is defined ? Does it retain ?

Comment: - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;  have you added these two

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check connection is nil or not

```
 xmlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                 initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", URL]]] delegate:self];
if (xmlConnection == nil){
    NSLog(@"Connection Error");
}
else{

    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] retain];

}
```